# Can I realloc() an unallocated pointer?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, realloc

Normally, realloc() is used to reallocate a previously allocated pointer:

```
int *DynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*SomeArbitraryValue);
// Some rando code where DynamicArray is used
DynamicArray = realloc(DynamicArray, sizeof(int)*SomeOtherArbitraryValue)
```

But can realloc() be used to directly allocate memory? As in

```
int *DynamicArray = realloc(/*...*/);
```

Can realloc() handle non-preallocated pointers?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just pass `NULL` to it's first argument.

The manpage of `realloc(3)` says ...

> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up  to  the minimum  of  the  old  and new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized.  If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by  an
>          earlier call to malloc(), calloc(), or realloc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

Answer (score 2):

As the answer by @ZhangBoyang tells you, yes, assuming one possible interpretation of your question. However the way you've worded your question ("non-preallocated pointers") suggests you may have misunderstanding of some of the concepts involved. `malloc` does not "allocate pointers". It allocates objects, and pointers are values that point to objects. The lifetime of those objects are not connected to the lifetime of any particular pointer pointing to them.

Passing a pointer to `realloc` doesn't "do anything to" the pointer. It does something to the object pointed to by it. If the pointer is uninitialized or invalid, the call has undefined behavior and bad things will happen. If the pointer is a null pointer, however, `realloc(ptr, n)` will behave exactly as `malloc(n)`.